Django Multi-Tenant App shows site cannot be reached when using tenant
I am making a login system using django with multitenant.
http://chatbot.com:8000/login/ points to the login page.
I want http://google.chatbot.com:8000/login/ to point to a login page specific to google.chatbot.com users.

Structure:
app:

app
login

Do i need to make changes in login views.py

or login urls.py

or app urls.py 
or all of them?
i am new to django and mutli tenant.
here is the github code: github code link
I watched this video but couldn't figure it out
